# Can't focus amazon.co.uk search box

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'd like to use a greasemonkey user script to auto-focus the amazon.co.uk search box when visiting that site.  To my surprise I didn't find a user script on the web for that purpose that worked for me.

Unlike amazon.com, the following does not focus the main search box on amazon.co.uk:

```
document.getElementById('twotabsearchtextbox').focus()
```

The search box is a text input and the getElementById does return that element.  So why does the .focus() not place the input focus on that input control?

Comment: This doesn't work in any browser it seems. ....maybe Amazon is screwing us over? :O

Comment: Thanks AwesomeGuy, I've removed the firefox tag

Answer (score -1):

Other items are stealing focus after you set it...

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('twotabsearchtextbox').focus()
};
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in a greasemonkey script, and I'm not sure why it would: in a JS shell after the page has fully loaded, document.getElementById(...).focus() fails to focus the search box.  Are you saying that something immediately grabs back focus even after load has completed?  In which case, why would executing this onload help?

Comment: I don't know... but it worked fine in a greasemonkey script for me... are you using the standard @grant GM_addStyle or whatever it is?

Comment: @CroadLangshan Without onload the script runs after the dom loads, but then amazon was popping up a signup button that took the focus.  The onload makes it wait until after that to run

Comment: If I personally, as a human, wait until after that before calling .focus() (without using GM at all), it still doesn't get the focus.

Comment: @CroadLangshan  Well, all I can say is that my example above along with "@grant       GM_addStyle" works great  on Firefox 24.0 with Greasemonkey 1.15

Comment: @CroadLangshan Try using a bandwidth meter like bitmeter and wait to do the .focus() until bandwidth usage shows zero (since I don't know what the very last thing on the page to load is)

Comment: I verified with firefox's built-in web developer tools network tab -- still doesn't focus the search box

Comment: @CroadLangshan I don't know... works for me with the versions of firefox and greasemonkey I mentioned above, don't know if it works with more recent versions... If I weren't on dialup I'd do a screencast of it working lol.  I suppose you've tried it logged in and not logged in?  Seems odd it worked for me and not you...  Do you have any other scripts running on that page?  I hate weirdness like this.